# Google Sheets For each checkbox true add 8 hours

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have created a column of checkboxes and underneath I have a total box, where if a box is checked I want to add 8 to the total box, I have tried a few ways but am at a loss. My Current formula is as follow:

`=QUERY(K3:K9,"where K = 0",1+8)`

This, however, is only returning the True or false option.  when all I'm trying to do is make it return a +8

Example

2 boxes checked that cell shows 16

5 boxes checked that cell shows 40

[image: Preview]

You can see what I am working on at this link and feel free to help with anything you want I do have it backed up and am struggling a lot with this.  I will return at 2 am EST

[My Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c09XFne9sCi-NzveJuQIS29tsW-gXVy_HW9TUCmsr5k/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(K3:K9=TRUE, 8, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

or:

```
=COUNTIF(K3:K9, TRUE)*8
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you player0 for helping me out with this =)